# Error in readOGR(dsn, layer) : could not find function "readOGR"

Tags: r

I am very new to R and so what does this mean? Does this tell me that I need to install some package named "ReadOGR"

I am following along using code written by someone else in an effort to generate a heat map. here is the current section to give some context.

```
   setwd("C:/Users/Someone/Documents/R")
   dsn <- "cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp"
   layer <- "cb_2017_us_state_20m"
   cb5 = readOGR(dsn, layer)
```

Installed rgdal to no success. Tried library(rgdal)

```
  library(rgdal) 
  Loading required package: sp
  rgdal: version: 1.3-9, (SVN revision 794)
   Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
  Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
  Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/trwilcox/Documents/R/win- 
  library/3.5/rgdal/gdal
  GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
  Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
  Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/someone/Documents/R/win- 
  library/3.5/rgdal/proj
  Linking to sp version: 1.3-1 
 Warning messages:
  1: package ‘rgdal’ was built under R version 3.5.2 
  2: package ‘sp’ was built under R version 3.5.2 
 > cb5 = readOGR(dsn, layer)
 Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = 
  use_iconv,  : 
   Cannot open data source
```

Comment: @JonnyCrunch, I installed "rgdal" by going to tool>install packages and still same error.

Comment: @JonnyCrunch, Edited the question. The result that I got is above.

Comment: Are files  ` "cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp"` and `"cb_2017_us_state_20m"` in `"C:/Users/Someone/Documents/R"`?

Comment: @JonnyCrunch, I was only sent one shapefile, "cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp.xml". Do I need a second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Someone/Documents/R")
dsn <- "cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp"
cb5 = readOGR(dsn)
```

Also, you can find the original files here: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html. Maybe there are some extra info there you want to use. 
You have to use the one with `.shp` not the `shp.xlm` If you do not have it, download from the link above!!!
It should work now, if not, happy to help you!

Comment: Still same error. I am lost, to say the least, going to remove R and reinstall and start from the beginning.

Comment: Does it matter that I am going to tools=> install packages and then running this code, installing tidyverse","ggplot2", "rgdal", "maptools", "mapproj", "rgeos", "plyr", "RColorBrewer","scales", "viridis", "ggthemes",

setwd("C:/Users/trwilcox/Documents/R")
> dsn <- "cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp"
> layer <- "cb_2017_us_state_20m"
> cb5 = readOGR(dsn, layer)

Comment: Just drop `layer` from `cb5 = readOGR(dsn, layer) `, use `cb5=readOGR(dsn)` and be sure that  "cb_2017_us_state_20m.shp"  is in C:/Users/trwilcox/Documents/R", if not, download it from  https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_state.html.

Comment: the error is still, Error in readOGR(dsn) : could not find function "readOGR". Its my understanding that the ReadOGR is part of rgdal? am I correct?

Comment: Not sure why it worked the second time around but I installed all of the packages and then did library(tidyverse)... and so on. After executing every single one, it works. Thanks for your patience.